# What's the name of the fusion of Gohan with Trunks?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

In Dragon Ball Heroes Gohan and Trunks fuse. What's the name of the warrior created by the fusion?

[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Future Gohanks** is the result of Future Gohan successful fusion with Future Trunks while using the fusion dance. This . was originally created in *Dragon Ball Heroes* and appears in Dragon Ball Fusion due to a collaboration between both the games. 
[Source](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Future_Gohanks)

Answer (score 1):

According to the game DragonBall Fusion, the name might be "Gohanks", but I don't know if we can consider it for DragonBall Heroes.